How to infer narrower type than explicitly declared?
I'm trying to find the most elegant solution to an inference problem I'm facing.
I am storing "filter" objects in an array. Each filter object has a known shape with including an id key. Finally, I would like to infer a union/tuple of all the id values included in the filter objects stored in the array. I'm struggling to get the inference working properly.
Here's my original approach:
type Filter = {
  id: string,
  label: string,
}

const filters: Filter[] = [
  {
    id: 'disabled',
    label: 'Off',
  },
  {
    id: 'firstname',
    label: 'First name',
  },
  {
    id: 'lastname',
    label: 'Last name',
  },
  {
    id: 'email',
    label: 'E-mail',
  },
] as const

type FilterId = typeof filters[number]['id'] // string

Unfortunately, since I'm declaring the filters const as being an array of Filter type, the inferred FilterId type is string, as defined in the Filter type.
A solution I found which achieves the desired FilterId is to use a function with a generic type argument:
type Filter = {
  id: string,
  label: string,
}

const createFilters = <T extends Filter[]>(filters: T) => filters

const filters = createFilters([
  {
    id: 'disabled',
    label: 'Off',
  },
  {
    id: 'firstname',
    label: 'First name',
  },
  {
    id: 'lastname',
    label: 'Last name',
  },
  {
    id: 'email',
    label: 'E-mail',
  },
] as const)

export type FilterId = typeof filters[number]['id'] // "disabled" | "firstname" | "lastname" | "email"

Is there a way to ask the compiler to narrow it down further without resorting to a function? The first approach feels so close yet so far, and a function that merely returns its first argument feels somewhat messy.
Also, I could ditch the Filter type altogether and the inference would work as expected, but I'd like to keep it around to ensure the filters array is constructed properly & benefit from autocompletion.
Any insight highly appreciated, curious to see whether this is possible without as little supporting code as possible.

satisfies is made for this. It is to be used when we want to ensure that some expression matches some type, but also want to keep the most specific type of that expression for inference purposes.
type Filter = {
  id: string,
  label: string,
}

const filters  = [
  {
    id: 'disabled',
    label: 'Off',
  },
  {
    id: 'firstname',
    label: 'First name',
  },
  {
    id: 'lastname',
    label: 'Last name',
  },
  {
    id: 'email',
    label: 'E-mail',
  },
] as const satisfies Filter[];

// Extract the type of the `id` field from the `filters` array
type FilterId = typeof filters[number]['id']; 

Playground

Wonderful, thanks for bringing this up! I definitely missed this in the docs. I’m glad to see there indeed was an elegant solution!
